# Flattening of list in scala

Tags: scala, flatten

I have jumped into Scala and started doing scala99, but I am stuck at P07 (flattening of list) following is my code and error message from the repl

```
scala> def flatten[A](x: List[A]): List[A] =
 | for(i <- x) yield i match {
 | case lst: List[Any] => flatten(lst)
 | case e => List(e)
 | }
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[List[Any]]
required: List[A]
   for(i <- x) yield i match {
         ^
```

Where am I wrong and what is the correct way?
Thanks.

Comment: The first thing that I can see is that your argument type is a `List[A]` instead of a `List[List[A]]`, as for the former there is nothing to "flatten". Also, why match on `List[Any]`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't get it: why is it _expecting_ `List[Any]` at that place? `for(i <- x)` is perfectly valid when `x` is `List[A]` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment to your question, I don't know why the compiler complains the way it does, but the root of the problem is that you are returning the same type as the input: if you flatten `List[List[Int]]` the output will be `List[Int]`, so what would the `A` be in your code???

I don't think type parameter really serves any purpose in this case, you are better off going with just `List[Any]`:

```
  def flatten(in: List[Any], out: List[Any] = Nil): List[Any] = in match { 
    case Nil => out.reverse
    case Nil :: t => flatten(t, out)
    case (h :: t) :: tail => flatten(h :: t ::: tail, out)
    case h :: t => flatten(t, h :: out)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use something like this

```
def flatten(t: List[Any]): List[Any]
  = t.flatMap {
        case s: List[_] => flatten(s)
        case x => List(x)
      }
```

In your case, the compiler complains because the function body clearly returns value of type `List[List[_]]` and there's nothing that makes `A` derivable from that type. At the same time, you cannot make `A` derivable from List since the top level list may contain scalar values. Finally, your code does not actually flatten the input, it just wraps every scalar value in a single element list.

Comment: the first `case` should be `=> s`. Also, this doesn't actually answer the question ...

Comment: @Dima nope, it should not as there's no limit on nesting depth, according to the problem definition.

Comment: @AlexK I want to solve this without using `flatMap`.

Comment: @AlexK I just want an alternative, solution using `flatMap` is also provided on the Scala 99 website, If I just want a solution then why did I post my question here!